# Mongodb node.js status true but not removing document from collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

In mongodb when I remove a document from collection the status is true, but its not removing from collection. when I'm again running the code the status become false, but it still exists in my collection.

```
exports.findOne = function findOne(req, res, next) {
    provider.findOne(req.params.id, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return next({
                status: 400,
                error: err
            });
        }
        if(!result){
            return res.send("no user")
        }

        res.json(result);

    });

};
```

this is to find a single document which runs perfectly fine as expected

```
exports.remove = function remove(req, res, next) {
    provider.remove(req.params.id, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return next({
                status: 400,
                error: err
            });
        }
        if(!result){
            return res.send("no user")
        }

        res.json(result);

    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to specify query `_id` explicitly for mongodb, so it'd be:

```
provider.remove({
  _id : db.ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.params.id) 
}, (err, result) => {
  // ..
})
```